# Problems with moment of inertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I totaly confused with these two problems can someone give any hints, or just final formula i get tired with it.

Find the velocity of (a) a cylinder and (b) a ring at the bottom of an inclined plane that is 2.00 m high. The cylinder and ring start from rest and roll down the plane.

Compute the velocity of a cylinder at the bottom of a plane 1.5 m high if (a) it slides without rotating on a frictionless plane and (b) it rotates on a rough plane.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: Its not a homework

Comment: Had you read to post garyp asked you to, you would have found out that whether it is actual homework or not is irrelevant. Also, what is the *"Peter J. Nolan?"* doing in the title? That's not a question.

Comment: I came here only for some hints nothing more

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a hint: If you make the assumption that the total mechanical energy of the system (moving object and gravitational field) doesn't change, then you will be able to start a solution. Be sure to include the kinetic energy due to both translational and rotational motion.